# Persistent setup of MariaDB in Docker container

Tags: mysql, docker, dockerfile, mariadb

I am trying to setup MariaDB in a Docker container for CI/CD testing.
However, the way I do it the DB does not exist when I log into the container.

Here's parts of my Dockerfile

```
FROM debian:stable-slim

RUN apt -y install mariadb-server mariadb-client
EXPOSE 3306
ADD ./DBShema.sql /db/DBShema.sql
RUN mysqld_safe \ 
    mysqladmin --silent --wait=30 ping \
    mysql < /db/DBShema.sql
```

Does not show my DB / tables.

```
MariaDB [(none)]> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
+--------------------+
3 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

How should that go properly to make the piped DB info persistent?

Comment: Can you share an example of the `dbschema.sql` file please?

Comment: Sorry, company use. But I can pipe it in manually when I run the MariaDB install in the container CLI and it would be there... Regular tables, nothing fancy.

Comment: What CI are you using ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are overcomplicating things. I do not see the point of starting from a plain Debian installation that requires you to install the RDBMS manually.

There are MariaDB images already made that you can use as a starting point for your CI images. Take the following `Dockerfile` as an example:

```
FROM mariadb:10.6.4-focal
COPY schema.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

This effectively copies over an sql script into the directory that is used to initialize the database on the first container start. This is mentioned in [this](https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb) portion of the documentation.

Once this is done the spun off container will contain all the changes included in the related sql file. I hope this is what you want.

Comment: Thanks, but I need to build from scratch, so I can not use that image. Is there a way to see the Dockerfile for those dockerhub images?

Comment: Most of them are hosted on GitHub so they are freely available. The question is, why do you want to build it yourself ?

Comment: No, you are right. I took the last 5min to think about it and I can have the maria container next to my custom container. Thats how it should be I guess...

Comment: Yeap. No need to reinvent the wheel. Plus on top of that pulling a ready made container guarantees stuff like version consistency and so on. Upvote the answer if you found it helpful

Comment: But what does the COPY do exactly? A SQL file is not an `initdb.d` executeable?

Comment: No it is not. This a custom script that resides within the same directory where the dockerfile lives. During buls it gets copied to the directory mentioned in the related documentation segment

Comment: Yeah, I did not RTFM , just did, makes sense. Thank you!